# Struggling with systemd and user permissions for backup script

Tags: ssh, scripting, systemd, sudo, rsync

I could use some help with figuring out the *right* way to accomplish what I need using systemd. I feel like I have backed myself in between a rock and a hard place and am not sure where to go. here is the condensed context:

I successfully setup a systemd *user* unit to run a backup script nightly that does a few things:

1. it uses my user's ssh key to ssh into another machine
2. it calls pass (i.e. my user's password store) to send a password to the remote machine for a command on the remote that requires sudo
3. it rsyncs some data from the remote machine to a backup drive

All this works great. Now the issue is that I need to also rsync some data locally to my backup drive, but the data is owned by root. Rsync fails with permission denied unless I use sudo to run the script. But the problem is *I can't figure out how to automate the use of sudo with a systemd user unit* - calling pass doesn't seem to work.

I read somewhere else that I should just use a normal systemd unit that runs as root to accomplish what I need, but the problem there is that all the other things that were working when running as a user unit break when running as root, because root doesn't have access to my user's ssh key or pass store.

TLDR: What is the best way to setup a systemd unit that can: 1) execute commands that require access to my ssh key and pass store, 2) also rsync data that requires elevated permissions, and 3) do both of these things in an automated way where I don't need to be at the keyboard to type in my user's password?